# Unit testing methods with logical dependencies on other classes

Tags: c#, design, unit-testing

Suppose I have an interface declaring the following method signature:

```
SearchResults SearchProducts(string type, string filter, string anotherFilter);
```

Inside a concrete implementation of this, I instantiate a helper class (call it `QueryBuilder`), built to ease the construction of strongly-typed search queries for the *specific* search library I'm using. I want to unit test `SearchProducts` (ideally by mocking the query builder), which means I need to decouple the method from `QueryBuilder`.

How do I do this appropriately when the two things are *logically coupled*? That is to say:

- It's not appropriate to pass an `IQueryBuilder` into the method as the implementation of `IQueryBuilder` is tightly coupled to the implementer of `ISearchProducts`, i.e. the types of the return values of `QueryBuilder`'s methods are specific to the library being used in the concrete `SearchService`.
- It's not appropriate to pass an instance of `IQueryBuilder` into the `SearchService` constructor (via DI or directly) as the *logical* scope of the query builder instance is local to the `SearchProducts` method call - it is instantiated in the method, its state is manipulated by adding sub-queries and a complete "query" is extracted *for this `SearchProducts` call*).

So, given the above, what's the appropriate way of handling this? It sounds like a case for a factory; however the implementation of this factory would be trivial and it seems a little contrived to define a factory interface and add a constructor parameter just for the sake of testability.

Is this indicative of a fundamental flaw in the design of my search interface? How do I decouple these things appropriately such that I can test both the search service and the query builder implementations in isolation?

Comment: That you're using `QueryBuilder` is an implementation detail. You can produce equally valid implementations that don't use it. So I wouldn't mock it, even if it increases the size of the system under test.

Comment: @CodesInChaos I had considered that, but `QueryBuilder` has methods with logic sufficiently complex that I would like to test it in isolation, which means that *not* mocking it undermines the usefulness of testing `SearchService`, no?

Answer (score 4):

This is the ideal use for [Inversion of Control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control), or specifically, Dependency Injection.  In your test context, your query builder is the mock; in your normal execution context, it's the real deal.  No need for a factory, just a different context.

Comment: That's all fine; except, as I said, the logical lifetime of the `QueryBuilder` is within the method - it's instantiated within the method, its state is manipulated with in the method and it is destructed within the method. Use of DI (be it parameter or constructor injection) would imply a query builder per search service instance, which does not make sense given the functionality of the query builder.

Comment: This is why a factory seems more appropriate - inject the factory and let the method instantiate the query builder. But it also seems overengineered.

Comment: That seems reasonable.  Alternatively, you could separate the QueryBuilder state from the QueryBuilder logic, like (N)Hibernate does with its `Criteria` class.  Then you could have a longer-lifetime QueryBuilder that is injected and re-used, and a per-method Criteria that is passed between QueryBuilder methods and the calling class.